# dequeReusableCellWIthIdentifier: loads cell that was previously deleted by the user

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm writing a little reminder app. When the user tries to set up a new reminder, a `UITableView` is brought up with different sections being different aspects about the reminder that the user edits. One of these sections I want to have dynamic rows so the user can click a plus sign in the first cell and another cell will appear below it. Once this happens a red x sign will replace the plus sign in the first cell so the user can also delete that cell. The problem I'm having is that when a cell is deleted, I'm calling `-deleteAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` but it seems that the cell is just being put into the reusable queue and not actually being deallocated. I know this because when a cell is deleted but then the user clicks the plus sign again, the old information in that cell (including the red x sign) is in the new cell that comes from `-dequeReusableCellWIthIdentifier:`. I cannot figure out a way to keep it from queueing the cell when I want it to deallocate it. Here is my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: that has to do with the cells I'm talking about.

```
static NSString *identifier2 = @"addTime";
    ReminderAddTimeTableViewCell *cell2 = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier2];
    if (cell2 == nil) {
        NSArray *cellnib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReminderAddTimeTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell2 = (ReminderAddTimeTableViewCell *)[cellnib objectAtIndex:0];

        [cell2.extra addTarget:self action:@selector(addTimeCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell2.extra.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell2.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return cell2;
```

And here are by `IBAction` methods that correspond to the adding and removing the cells:

```
-(IBAction)addTimeCell:(UIButton*)sender{
    timeCellCount ++;
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag+1 inSection:1];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path,nil];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender removeTarget:self action:@selector(addTimeCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(removeTimeCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];}

-(IBAction)removeTimeCell:(UIButton*)sender{
    for(int i = sender.tag+1; i <= timeCellCount; i++){
        ((ReminderAddTimeTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:1]]).extra.tag --;
    }
    timeCellCount --;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green-plus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender removeTarget:self action:@selector(removeTimeCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(addTimeCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:1];
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path,nil];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

I have tagged the buttons so I know what cell I am dealing with, as well as set a global variable called timeCellCount that keeps the total number of cells. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the cell, not delete it. Update it's views by overriding the `prepareForReuse` method.

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse):

> Prepares a reusable cell for reuse by the table view's delegate.
>
> `- (void)prepareForReuse`
>
> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked
>   just before the object is returned from the UITableView method
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you
>   should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to
>   content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table
>   view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always
>   reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not
>   have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you
>   override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass
>   implementation.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: How then do I keep the tableview from inserting these deleted and restored cells when the user scrolls the table out of view of these cells then back into view.

Comment: That's the thing @ddresner8, you're not suppose to prevent the tableview from reusing them. The reason why `UITableView` is optimized is that because it reuses cells, meaning that nothing is being deleted. If you need two different type of cells, then use a second cell identifier `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SomeOtherIdentifier"];`.

Comment: Then does that mean once a user edits a cell that I must make a new cell with a new identifier that contains the inputted information in order to keep that cell at that location when the user scrolls out of view and then back into view?

Comment: No, by using two cells identifier you can have two different type of cell. For instance, one that could display a couple images and an other one that would only display text. `UITableViewCell` is a display component meant to be reused. The data is suppose to be saved elsewhere in your `UIViewController`. I suggest you to start with a simple `UITableView` tutorials to really understand how it works. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/